# HttpClient request fails in .Net Core, on mac

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've got a local .net core 2.0 console application, that attempts to send a post request to my local running .net core web app, via a `HttpClient`:

```
var webClient = new HttpClient();
webClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
var result = await _webClient.PostAsync("some_location", data);
```

On windows, this seems to work OK. But on macOS, I get an error:

```
System.Net.Http.CurlException

Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAgent.FinishRequest(StrongToWeakReference`1 easyWrapper,CURLcode messageResult) 
End of inner exception
```

I assumed that this was because my local web app was using an SSL certificate that wasn't trusted - I'm setting Kestrel up in development to use SSL like this:

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
    {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.pfx", "password");
            });
    })
```

However, I've gone to the effort of making a local SSL cert that is trusted (so when I visit the site in chrome I get no SSL warnings), and I'm still seeing this error from my console app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check in safari? It should use same APIs as safari, chrome may do something different.

Comment: Ah that's interesting - I did, it works fine in Safari too, but if I run `curl` against my web app, that also fails: `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.`